# Determine if multiple records on left-join

Tags: sql, left-join

In a CRM for construction projects, the clients, architects and other contractors all exist as ACCOUNTs. The table PROJ_AC_LINK links ACCOUNT to PROJECT, and the field PROJ_AC_LINK.ROLE_TYPE_ID specifies what that link represents (e.g. Joe Simms is linked to project 101 under the role 'architect').

The CRM database, and user interface, allows users to link multiple accounts to a project under the same role. In some cases this is fine (project has 2 architects) but in some cases it's not (there should only ever be one 'client' that we invoice for the project). I can't change the CRM.

A query from a separate system seeks to obtain the SITE_ADDRESS and CLIENT_ADDRESS, and assumes that there will only be one client linked to each project. It queries it like so (205 is the code for role 'client'):

```
SELECT 
PROJECT.ADDRESS AS SITE_ADDRESS, 
ACCOUNT.ADDRESS AS CLIENT_ADDRESS
FROM PROJECT
LEFT JOIN PROJ_AC_LINK ON 
    (PROJ_AC_LINK.PROJECT_ID = PROJECT.PROJECT_ID 
    AND 
    PROJ_AC_LINK.ROLE_TYPE_ID = '205')
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT ON PROJ_AC_LINK.ACCT_ID = ACCOUNT.ACCT_ID
```

If there is no client linked to a project, this query still returns a SITE_ADDRESS, but returns NULL for CLIENT_ADDRESS, which is exactly what I want.

The people using that system know to tell the CRM people if they get a blank client address through. However, I need to cater for the possibility of there being more than one client linked to a project.

Is there a way I can make CLIENT_ADDRESS return NULL (or custom text) in the case where there is more than one record in PROJ_AC_LINK for that project for that role.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a group by statement and then a case statement based on the count of records you return.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT p.ADDRESS AS SITE_ADDRESS, 
       a.ADDRESS AS CLIENT_ADDRESS
FROM PROJECT p LEFT JOIN
     (select a.PROJECT_ID, a.ADDRESS
      from ACCOUNT a join
           Proj_AC_Link pa
           on pa.Acct_id = a.Acct_Id
      where pa.ROLE_TYPE_ID = '205'
      group by ac.Project_id
      having count(*) = 1
     ) addr
     ON P.PROJECT_id = addr.project_id
```

This just returns singleton addresses from the account table.

Comment: I see the idea, but this actually does the same as original query: it returns 2 rows if there are 2 accounts like as clients. I think the sub-select should be on the linking table, I'm away to experiment with changing it around...